# Update one Jtree's model on the basis of another Jtree's selection

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` using a `DefaultTreeModel` and `DefaultMutableTreeNodes` which contain a business object instance.

When I select a leaf node, I know the business object instance is one of two classes that share the same parent class.

I have a second `JTree` also using a `DefaultTreeModel` and `DefaultMutableTreeNodes` which represent certain types of data that appear in the business object instances.

I wish to update the second `JTree`'s model so that I can select/drag/drop a particular leaf node and then display that data elsewhere.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this reading the various tutorials and other web resources that I think are relevant, however I am having trouble understanding how I can do this "correctly".

The closest I can get at the moment is to respond to the selection event in the first `JTree` by subscribing the second `JTree` to selection events, pulling the business object instance out of the selected node and doing a is instanceOf operation to decide what to do next. This of course feels horribly wrong.

How can I best achieve updating the second `JTree`'s view depending upon which class instance is selected in the first `JTree`'s view?

Comment: Why does this feel 'horribly wrong' to you?

Comment: Trying to do `if (myNode.getUserObject instanceOf MyRedBusinessObject)` seems like poor design. I am thinking that something like `myNode.getTree2Model` is what I want, but I don't understand how I can call that on myNode without knowing what it is apriori and casting it appropriately

Comment: You can implement the MutableTreeNode interface yourself and directly abstract your business objects to the UI. The benefit of that is that you can have subclasses with different behaviour for different types of business objects. You could also add the different behaviour to the business objects while using a DefaultMutableTreeNode, but that would break correct layering in your design - the business layer would need to know about the UI layer.

Comment: But I don't think instanceof is such a bad thing in this case. I guess it depends on how 'core' the swing code is to your application and how much time you want to spend on it.

Comment: thanks. 


it isn't that the instanceof approach is a particularly big deal... but I am switching this stuff away from Matlab because it just became too painful to manage... I am just trying to take the opportunity to do things well where I can.

Comment: i'm also not sure I am clear on what should implement the `MutableTreeNode` ... won't I still end up with an event handler that needs to know apriori the node's type is, or does this allow me to have a `myNode.getOtherTreeNodes` that will respond differently?